# C# reflection activator create instance using a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Let's say I have the following class definition :

```
List<SomeClass>...
public class SomeClass
{
   int Id {get; set;}
}
```

and in another place in my project , I get this type List I want to somehow decompose it, whjich means create an instance of the generic passed parameter in this case (SomeClass)

```
 public T Decompose (object toDecompose)
{
   if (toDecompose.GetType().IsGenericType())
   {
     Types[] genericParams= toDecompose.GetType().GetGenericParameters();
      something similar to ...return Activator.CreateInstance<genericParams[0]>; -- which does not compile
   }
}
```

so the returned object should be an instance of SomeClass..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  Activator.CreateInstance(genericParams[0]);
```